# Simplest Way To Change Scene In Swift + Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I am just wondering what the simplest way to change scenes in Swift + Sprite Kit is?

Comment: that would probably be reading the sprite kit programming guide - it's all in there. If you already know a way to change scenes and it's too complicated, then post that code. It's supposed to be a one liner with presentScene: in it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

when changing between scenes, you're going to need to set up a transition, how the scene will change to the next and define which scene you want to transition to.

For the transition,

```
 var transition:SKTransition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1)
```

The `fadeWithDuration`can be replaced with any `SKTransition`  a list of which can be found in the documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKTransition_Ref/index.html

as for defining the scene,

```
var scene:SKScene = GameScene(size: self.size)
```

You're stating which scene you wish to transition to, in this case `GameScene`, but should be replaced with whichever scene you wish to transition to.

In order to start the transition, call:

```
self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
```

Which will move to the scene `scene` which was set up in the line prior, using the transition `transition` which was also defined.

Comment: Minor update: Due to refactoring in later versions of Swift/SpriteKit, the fade method in the first line is now `SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 1)`.  Other than that, this answer is simple, straightforward, and to the point.  Thanks!